# Representing boolean with enum options in json to generate json schema with genson

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I am trying to use genson python library to build a json schema which then will be used on frontend to generate a dynamic form. In this case I want frontend to create a radio button based on schema values. But I have issue with boolean types. For example, this is how my json data looks like

```
configuration = {
            "displayType":  {"Opaque":True, "Border":False}
        } #Out of the two options here, only one of them can be true.
```

and this is how i create schema from it.

```
 builder = SchemaBuilder(schema_uri="https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema")
 builder.add_object(configuration)
 schema = builder.to_schema()
```

The generated schema looks like below,

```
{
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'Opaque': {
            'type': 'boolean'
        },
        'Border': {
            'type': 'boolean'
        }
    },
    'required': ['Border', 'Opaque']
}
```

As seen above in the required field I need to have info regarding the mutual relationship within one another but I just have a required field. Can anyone help me to modify the json data accordingly?

Comment: Please note the `genson` tag has established use for an unrelated Java library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your schema:

```
'not': {
    'properties': {
        'Opaque': { 'const': true },
        'Border': { 'const': true }
    }
}
```

In pseudocode, that is: "if Opaque is true and Border is true, then validation is false."

Alternatively, because you require both Opaque and Border to be set, and they can only be true or false, you could use if/then/else, as in: "if Opaque is true, then Border is false, else Border is true":

```
'if': {
    'properties': {
        'Opaque': { const: true }
    }
},
'then': {
    'properties': {
        'Border': { const: false }
    }
},
'else': {
    'properties': {
        'Border': { const: true }
    }
}
```

You can read more about adding conditions to your schema here: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for the answer. But In my case I need the json itself not the schema. The schema is generated by genson builder. I need the json object that builds a schema that you have provided.

Comment: Why? instead of `schema = builder.to_schema()` just do `schema = ...data structure `.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to build my own schema builder. But your answer helped.